# Maximo custom field in non persistent table

Tags: customization, maximo

How can we add a new custom field in maximo Issue Current Item dialog. Where ISSUECURRENTITEM is a non-persistent table

Comment: No one is here to comment???

Comment: Does this link help you? http://www.xcentricway.ca/tutorial01.htm  How To Create A Custom Dialog Box In Maximo Allowing User To Email BIRT Report

Comment: Thanks for ur reply man, but its a different case here.  In inventory application, there is a default dialogue ISSUE CURRENT ITEM,  what I want is to add some morentext fields in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

atlast I found a solution thanks to [SASHULL](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/profiles/html/profileView.do?userid=270003PYB8)

**the solution is :**

Adding an attribute to the ISSUECURRENTITEM is easy (go to Database Configuration and add the attribute to the ISSUECURRENTITEM object) but the challenge is capturing the data in the MATUSETRANS table. Since this is a non-persistent object, java classes copy the data from the non-persistent object to the persistent object MATUSETRANS. If you're on Maximo 7.5 or 7.6, you should be able to get that data from an automation script.

​Your launch point would be on MATUSETRANS object Add event and you would want something like below. Be sure to replace the attribute names with the appropriate names. I left in my notes from my script to help explain what's going on but if you have questions about any of it let me know.

```
# Purpose is for the Issue Current Item dialog, they want a custom field that would be stored on MATUSETRANS.
# Since it's a non-persistent object, we need a way to crossover the value with an automation script.
owner= mbo.getOwner()

# During save of the Issue Current Item, it goes up to the Inventory record to create the MATUSETRANS record.
# We need to go from MATUSETRANS->INVENTORY->ISSUECURRENTITEM to get the value

if owner and owner.getRecordMboName()=="INVENTORY":
    issueitemMbo=owner.getMboSet("ISSUECURRENTITEM").getMbo(0)
    if issueitemMbo:
           mbo.setValue("MATUSETRANSFIELD",      issueitemMbo.getString("ISSUECURRENTITEMFIELD"))
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Add your fields to **ISSUECURRENTITEM** object using Database configuration

2) Go to application designer and open **Inventory (INVENTOR)** application.

3) Click **'Edit Dialogs'** from the toolbar

4) Open Dialog - **ISSUE** (Label:Issue Current Item)

5) Add the field you configured in the database to the dialog as you like.